# uncheck radiobutton - PyQt4

Tags: python, radio-button, pyqt4

In this sample of code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QButtonGroup
import sys

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent=None)

        button = QPushButton('Button')
        self.radiobutton1 = QRadioButton('1')
        self.radiobutton2 = QRadioButton('2')
        #self.group = QButtonGroup()
        #self.group.addButton(self.radiobutton1)
        #self.group.addButton(self.radiobutton2)       
        #self.group.setExclusive(False)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        button.clicked.connect(self.my_method)

    def my_method(self):
        self.radiobutton1.setChecked(False)
        self.radiobutton2.setChecked(False)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

When the button clicked I expect the selected radioButton to be unchecked, but that never happens. If I uncomment the comment lines and run the code, then I can uncheck radioButtons. But another problem occurs. Because the group is not exclusive, I can set both radioButtons checked something that must not happens.

What should I do to be able to unckeck the buttons while only one button at a time can be selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels like cheating, but it works:

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Button')
        button.clicked.connect(self.my_method)

        self.radiobutton1 = QtGui.QRadioButton('1')
        self.radiobutton2 = QtGui.QRadioButton('2')

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radiobutton2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
        self.group.addButton(self.radiobutton1)
        self.group.addButton(self.radiobutton2)       

    def my_method(self):
        self.group.setExclusive(False)        
        self.radiobutton1.setChecked(False)
        self.radiobutton2.setChecked(False)
        self.group.setExclusive(True)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

As you've pointed out, when `self.group.setExclusive(False)` is set, you can untoggle both radio buttons.

And when `self.group.setExclusive(True)`, only one radio button can be set.

So `my_method` simply calls `self.group.setExclusive(False)` so it can unset both radio buttons, then resets `self.group.setExclusive(True)`.

---

PS. I think `parent` should not be set to `None` on this line:

```
super(Form, self).__init__(parent = None)
```

since if a non-trivial `parent` is sent to `Form`, you would probably want to pass that `parent` on to `QDialog.__init__`.

Comment: QButtonGroup is in QtWidgets (not QtGui) in PyQt5

Answer (score 1):

To anyone looking for a simple fix to this very annoying problem, connect each button to a `slot` that controls the `CheckState` of the other buttons.

Simply add the list of buttons you want to a `QButtonGroup`, get the list of buttons, check that the `sender` is not the same button, and uncheck others.

Assuming that you instantiate your buttons in a loop, you can easily implement this:

```
self.bg = QButtonGroup()
self.bg.setExclusive(False)

for button in list_of_buttons:
    self.bg.addButton(button)
    button.clicked.connect(self.uncheck_other_buttons)


def uncheck_other_btns(self):
    for button in self.bg.buttons():  # returns the list of all added buttons
        if self.sender() != button:   # in PyQt5, button.objectName() fails if name isn't set, 
                                      # instead, simply check that the signal sender() object  
                                      # is not the same object as the clicked button
            button.setChecked(False)  # then set all other buttons to be unchecked
```