# How to uncheck a checked radio buttons in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qradiobutton

Im making a quiz and after my next button is pressed i want the the radio buttons to be unchecked but this isnt happening. Here is where i put the radio buttons.

```
self.answers = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self) 
self.Correctanswer = QRadioButton()
self.Incorrectans1 = QRadioButton()
self.Incorrectans2 = QRadioButton()
self.Incorrectans3 = QRadioButton()
self.answers.addButton(self.Correctanswer)
self.answers.addButton(self.Incorrectans1)
self.answers.addButton(self.Incorrectans2)
self.answers.addButton(self.Incorrectans3)
self.answers.buttonClicked.connect(self.QuestionCheck)
self.Correctanswer.setAutoExclusive(True)
self.Incorrectans1.setAutoExclusive(True)
self.Incorrectans2.setAutoExclusive(True)
self.Incorrectans3.setAutoExclusive(True)
```

Here the subroutine which is connected to my next button. And here i try to set the radio buttons to be clear but that isnt happening. The radio button still has its previous choice from the last question.

```
def Showquestions2(self):
    self.Questionum.setText("Question 2")
    self.Correctanswer.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans1.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans2.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans3.setChecked(False)
    self.ismultichoiceButton.clicked.connect(self.Showquestions3)
```

Could anyone tell me where im going wrong? thanks

Comment: If you look more carefully at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29324090/984421) to one of your previous questions, you'll find the solution.

Comment: ohh right, thanks i saw that. The index in the parentheses put me off so i didnt try it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def Showquestions2(self):
    self.group.setExclusive(False)
    self.Questionum.setText("Question 2")
    self.Correctanswer.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans1.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans2.setChecked(False)
    self.Incorrectans3.setChecked(False)
    self.ismultichoiceButton.clicked.connect(self.Showquestions3)
    self.group.setExclusive(True)
```

Try this code for further refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689909/uncheck-radiobutton-pyqt4)

Comment: Thanks it worked a charm, changed self.group for answers and it worked.

Comment: in PyQt 5 use QtWidget instead of QtGui